# Should one put `while true` inside of a clojure core.async thread?

Tags: multithreading, clojure, core.async

I have this producer/consumer pattern i've been making with core.async `thread` functions like so:

```
(defn -db-producer-factory [order-ids-chan next-chan]
  (thread
    (while true
      (do
        (let [order-id (<!! order-ids-chan)]
          (condp = order-id
            :finished (do
                        (>!! next-chan :finished))
            (supress-w-nextexc
              (->>
                ; get denorm'd order
                (-> (r/-get-order :live order-id)
                    denorm/order->denormalized)
                ; put in a map to avoid nils
                (hash-map :data)
                (>!! next-chan)))))))))
```

However when i read [the documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/thread) for `thread`, it says:

> Executes the body in another thread, returning immediately to the
>   calling thread. Returns a channel which will receive the result of the
>   body when completed.

It sounds like its expecting thread to be called one-off; not that its built for a `while` loop within it.

Should i not do `while true` in a `thread` block? Or will the thread be cleaned up when i close the `thread`'s result chan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread won't be cleaned up for sure, so, yes, probably you shouldn't use `while true` loop. Instead of it you may use loop with exit condition.

Common pattern is to make your `go`-routines (simply saying, loops that are executed on other thread) dependent on your input channels. In other words, when channel that provides data to `go`-routine is closed - `go`-routine is shut down.

I've rewritten your code a little bit, probably missed something, but I hope you'll get the idea:

```
(defn -db-producer-factory [order-ids-chan next-chan]
  (go-loop [order-id (<! order-ids-chan)]
    (condp = order-id

      nil
      ;; exiting
      nil

      :finished (do
                  (>! next-chan :finished)
                  (recur (<! order-ids-chan)))
      (do
        (supress-w-nextexc
         (->>
          (-> (r/-get-order :live order-id)
              denorm/order->denormalized)
          (hash-map :data)
          (>! next-chan)))
        (recur (<! order-ids-chan))))))
```

Also I've replaced `thread` call with `go` call. This is "lightweight" version of `thread`, that uses thread parking instead of blocking native thread. If you need OS threads, you may replace it with `(thread (loop ...`.

Comment: i have a hard time believing the `loop` inside `thread` would be able to be disposed of/deallocated/garbage collected, but you did answer my question!

Comment: got it cleared up for me in clojure #core-async slack room. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the discussion here:  http://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/

The most important sentence is:

> The reason you should use thread instead of a go block when you’re
>   performing a long-running task is so you don’t clog your thread pool.

Long-running tasks are exactly what Java threads are made for.  Since you have a long-running task (it appears?) it should have it's own thread.

The JVM can handle a thousand user threads w/o problem on modern hardware.

Comment: The question wasn't about having a long-running thread. It was about having a long-running thread that would keep running even after it was no longer needed, which could cause a memory leak.